# How to stop Chrome's "Set up Chrome" page from appearing?

Tags: google-chrome

Recent versions of Google Chrome automatically open the "Set up Chrome" page:
[image]

This page opens up by itself and what seems to be arbitrary times.  If I close it and just use my computer normally, at some point later I could be reading an article and then Chrome opens this page by itself.

How do I stop this annoying thing from happening without actually signing into Chrome?

Comment: There used to be a link at the bottom to skip that and set up later, is it gone now?

Comment: It seems to be gone.  What's in the screenshot is all that is on the page.